# decryption of encrypted messages on the server side

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, digital-signature, encryption-asymmetric

I'm working on an client-server application. I have to use the asymmetric Cryptography. The client encrypts his message and the digital signature is created.

I store the message and the signature in a Vector and I send this Vector to the server. 
The server receives this Vector.

In the server side, first I check the signature to see if the server is communicating with the right client, when the signature is good, I'm trying to decrypt the message but the result of this decryption is not good.
The problem concerns only the encryption/decryption, I don't have problems with the rest of the code.

CLIENT SIDE:

```
private void payActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream()); 
    ObjectOutputStream dos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

    Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    byte[] message = concatMess.getBytes("UTF-8");
    cipherText = encryptCipher.doFinal(message);
    texteCrypteStr= Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
    System.out.println("MESSAGE: "+cipherText);

    //SIGNATURE DU MESSAGE
    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA","BC");
    System.out.println("Initialisation de la signature");
    signature.initSign(keyPri);
    System.out.println("Hachage du message");
    signature.update(cipherText);
    System.out.println("Generation des bytes");
    bytesign = signature.sign(); 
    String texteSignStr= Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytesign);
    System.out.println("CLIENT SIGNATURE: "+texteSignStr);

    Vector vecByte = new Vector();
    vecByte.add(bytesign);
    vecByte.add(cipherText);
    dos.writeObject(vecByte);
    received = dis.readUTF();
}
```

SERVER SIDE:

```
public class PaiementHandler{
    Vector<byte[]> receivedVec = new Vector<byte[]>();   
    String toreturn; 
    receivedVec = ((Vector)disr.readObject());

    System.out.println("v1 "+receivedVec.get(0));
    System.out.println("v2 "+receivedVec.get(1));
    Vector<String> received = null;

    //RECUPERATION CLE PUBLIQUE
    KeyStore ksv = null;
    ksv = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");
    ksv.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\KEYSTORE\\keystore.p12"),"gogo".toCharArray());
    System.out.println("Recuperation du certificat");
    X509Certificate certif = (X509Certificate)ksv.getCertificate("toto");
    System.out.println("Recuperation de la cle publique");
    PublicKey publicKey = certif.getPublicKey(); 

    //VERIFICATION DE LA SIGNATURE

    System.out.println("\nVérification de la signature");
    System.out.println("*** Cle publique recuperee = "+publicKey.toString());
    System.out.println("Debut de verification de la signature construite");
    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA", "BC");
    signature.initVerify(publicKey);
    signature.update(receivedVec.get(1));
    System.out.println("Verification de la signature construite");
    boolean ok = signature.verify(receivedVec.get(0));
    if(ok){
        System.out.println("signature verified with success");
        //DECHIFFREMENT DU MESSAGE
        try{
            Cipher dechiffrement = Cipher.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
            dechiffrement.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,publicKey);
            System.out.println("AVANT DECH");
            byte[] texteDecode = dechiffrement.doFinal(receivedVec.get(1));
            String texteDecodeStr = new String(texteDecode, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println("Vecteur: "+texteDecodeStr);
     }
}
```

Here is the message that the client sends to the server : "2222-2222-2222.30 3 1 1 2019-07-30 2019-07-31 90 40". So this message is encrypted and is sent with the client signature in a vector to the server (they're both byte[]).

The server receives this vector, It check first the signature, when it's ok then it decrypts the message.
Here is the result of the decryption when it's translated in String :

�ߩ�u�5�&�]��{��^��S?u2_��l��i������������b#��fCA�5�Ri,&�P   �T��3�4��:���Rm���~�W���DG��ga��i����vR

I don't understand why I have this result ...
I'm trying to code it like this website https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/rsa-encryption-decryption but I don't know where is the problem

Comment: You specify UTF-8 when encoding and decoding (good, but you may want to use StandardCharsets.UTF_8 rather than "UTF-8"), but when you print the message out it is being printed in whatever the platform default character set is on each system, and possibly interpreted as a different encoding by the terminal emulator you're viewing the results on. You may want to check a hash of the data to see if it's really different.

Comment: This is a bit messy. The core problem is that you are trying to decrypt with the public key. Remember: you sign with **your** private key and encrypt with the recipient's public key. The recipient verifies with **your** public key and decrypts with his private key. You don't both share a keypair, that completely defeats the purpose of asymmetric cryptography. After you get that concept working there are a host of important improvements you should make to this.

Comment: Throw it all away and use TLS. It is considerably more secure than your scheme. If you need digital signatures use `SignedObject`.

Comment: @DavidConrad So the problem can come from the characters encoding/decoding ? I have some difficult with these

Comment: @JamesKPolk Yes you're right, I corrected it. Now I have this result after decrypting the message : D�\Au;�#x#N�Cpb�ƨΜ��u���6��P�du�{���*222222-2222-2222.30 3 1 1 2019-07-30 2019-07-31 90 40. We can see clearly the message from the client at the end of the decrypted message but how can I correct it and obtain the full right message ?

Comment: @user207421 I can't, we're obliged to work in this way. Our teacher wants it.

Comment: First off, don't rely on defaults. Always specify the full *algorithm/mode/padding* transformation string to `Cipher.getInstance()`. Second, I'm not sure why you're using the "BC" provider here and there but not everywhere. Don't specify a provider unless you have a good reason to specify a provider. I don't see one.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I corrected the Cipher.getInstance parameter as you said. About the provider, the method getInstance need it as parameter and in our book they use Bouncy castle as provider that's why I use it. But I think that the problem come from the encoding/decoding of the message but I don't know how to correct it. I already work on the same kind of application but with symmetrics keys and I had no problem with the provider.

Comment: Always specify the full algorithm/mode/padding transformation string to Cipher.getInstance(). Like `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding")`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thanks to this : https://gist.github.com/nielsutrecht/855f3bef0cf559d8d23e94e2aecd4ede

I had to encode the result of the encrypted message in base64 and decode it **BEFORE** decrypting it.

CLIENT SIDE:

```
                Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding");
                encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
                String concatMess="";
                int k = 0;
                while(k<vec.size()){
                    concatMess+=vec.get(k);
                    if(k+1<vec.size())
                        concatMess+="!";
                    k+=1;
                }
                System.out.println("VECTOR:"+concatMess);
                byte[] message = concatMess.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                cipherText = encryptCipher.doFinal(message);
                System.out.println("MESSAGE byte: "+cipherText);
                cipherTextString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
```

SERVER SIDE :

```
            Cipher dechiffrement = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding", "BC");
            dechiffrement.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,keyPri);
            System.out.println("AVANT DECH");
            byte[] texteDecode = dechiffrement.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode((String)receivedVec.get(1)));
            String texteDecodeStr = new String(texteDecode, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Thank to this solution I have the correct message.
Thank you for your advices and your explanations.